# Can't display lot's of barcodes ,using IDAutomationHC39M for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to display a list of barcodes in asp.net i've searched everywhere and i found IDAutomationHC39M as free .when i use the code whith a one string i get the barcode with the number displayed on the bottom of the barecode ,now i've tried to use it with a array of string i get's the list of barecodes but SYSTEM.S displayed in the bottom,so it's doesn't read the array of strings ,any help i'll be so glad ,here is my code

```
public String[] Action = { "12345", "76543", "34567", "87654", "34567" };
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string barCode = txtCode.Text; 
    for (int i=1;i<=Action.Count();i++)
    {
         System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
         using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(Action.Length * 40, 80))
         {
             using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
             {
                 Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 16);
                 PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                 SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                 SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                 graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
                 graphics.DrawString("*" + Action + "*", oFont, blackBrush, point);
             }//
             using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
             {
                 bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                 byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                 Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                 imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
             }
         }    
             plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
         }        
}
```

and in the client side i have a placeholder

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plBarCode" runat="server" />
```

Can you tell me what's going wrong with my code?

Comment: Not relevant to your question directly, but you may need to set `graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;` to avoid anti-aliasing on your barcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Replace

```
graphics.DrawString("*" + Action + "*", oFont, blackBrush, point);
```

with

```
graphics.DrawString("*" + Action[i-1] + "*", oFont, blackBrush, point);
```

Longer answer:
What you are doing is passing the whole array each single iteration run . But if you want to iterate over the `Action` array, you need to access the current string of each iteration run. That is done by passing the index of the array in brackets (`[i-1]`). It needs to be `i-1` because, as Rawling pointed out, your `i` is running from 1 to `Count`,  but arrays use zero based indices (the first element is referred to as `[0]`).

Comment: It'll need to be `i-1` because of his indexing, but that's another issue.

Comment: i did (int i=1; i<action.count()) instead of (i<=)